# Error when i add datetimetype pole form in symfony3/4 on openwrt LAMP server

Tags: php, symfony

I making my project on openwrt and when i try make form with pole datetimetype in symfony 3 i have an error which I can not overcome. On Xampp this project work!

```
datefmt_create: date formatter creation failed: U_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ERROR

IntlDateFormatter->__construct('pl', 2, -1, object(IntlTimeZone), 1, '')
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php (line 87)

root@VigoradoNetwork:/www1/homesystem# php-cgi bin/symfony_requirements
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqlnd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'http.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/http.so (Error loading shared library libmbedx509.so.0: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/lib/php/http.so)), /usr/lib/php/http.so.so (Error loading shared library /usr/lib/php/http.so.so: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.9
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<br />
<b>Deprecated</b>:  Function create_function() is deprecated in <b>/www1/homesystem/var/SymfonyRequirements.php</b> on line <b>551</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught IntlException: Constructor failed in /www1/homesystem/var/SymfonyRequirements.php:658
Stack trace:
#0 /www1/homesystem/var/SymfonyRequirements.php(658): Collator-&gt;__construct('fr_FR')
#1 /www1/homesystem/bin/symfony_requirements(6): SymfonyRequirements-&gt;__construct()
#2 {main}
  thrown in <b>/www1/homesystem/var/SymfonyRequirements.php</b> on line <b>658</b><br />
```

in `php.ini` i have 128mb memory for php

The same error show in symfony 3,4 and 4,1

Answer (score 0):

Two things: 1) why running it as root? 2) Using `php-cgi` or whatever instead of just `./bin/<whatever>` **could use different php.ini files** and, therefore, different options (i.e. less RAM assigned). This is what the note says, and you can also check requirements from the browser via `web/config.php` script.

Also, make sure the `var/SymfonyRequirements.php` script corresponds to the same symfony version you're using.

Comment: Symfony version and php version is ok, the same error show,s on version 3,4 symfony and 4,1, when i copy all to the xamp everything works good, when i back to the Openwrt where i have LAMP server error back. I discovered when i comment in App\Form\Type\MyType.php line with DataTimeType, everything works again good but i dont have form with datatime on web... I see too rest of type pole in form work too

Comment: + log from this event: [2018-10-08 06:43:59] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception IntlException: "datefmt_create: date formatter creation failed: U_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ERROR" at /www1/homesystem4/vendor/symfony/form/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php line 100 {"exception":"[object] (IntlException(code: 7): datefmt_create: date formatter creation failed: U_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ERROR at /www1/homesystem4/vendor/symfony/form/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php:100)"} []

Comment: 1) i running it as root becouse i login on router throught ssh as root

Comment: I have some idea, in phpmyadmin i have problems with Locale, when i disable it in phpmyadmin it start works, maybe here i will try ? but i don;t know how..